# Firestore - Difference between DocumentSnapshot and QueryDocumentSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The documentation says

> A QueryDocumentSnapshot contains data read from a document in your Firestore database as part of a query. The document is guaranteed to exist and its data can be extracted using the getData() or get() methods.
>
> QueryDocumentSnapshot offers the same API surface as DocumentSnapshot. Since query results contain only existing documents, the exists() method will always return true and getData() will never be null.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot

But it doesn't explain when I should use one over the other. I tried both in a `SnapshotListener` on a `Collection` and both worked.

```
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    notebookRef.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onEvent(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
            if (e != null) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error while loading!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.d(TAG, e.toString());
                return;
            }

            String allNotes = "";

            for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot : queryDocumentSnapshots) {


                Note note = documentSnapshot.toObject(Note.class);

                String title = note.getTitle();
                String description = note.getDescription();

                allNotes += "\nTitle: " + title + " Description: " + description;

            }

            textViewData.setText(allNotes);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You don't ever make a decision about which one to use - the API tells you which one you're getting.  In the code you've shown, your listener is receiving a QuerySnapshot which yields multiple QueryDocumentSnapshot objects.  DocumentSnapshot doesn't ever show up here - you're not using them both at the same time.  You have a variable called `documentSnapshot`, but that's not the same thing.

Comment: If I replace `QueryDocumentSnaptshot` for `DocumentSnaptshot` in the for loop, the app behaves the same.

Answer (score 29):

As you've stated:

> QueryDocumentSnapshot offers the same API surface as DocumentSnapshot

**This is because [QueryDocumentSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/QueryDocumentSnapshot) is a subclass of DocumentSnapshot.**  This means that every QueryDocumentSnapshot can be assigned (downcast) to a variable of type DocumentSnapshot.  They do exactly the same thing, except for the difference between them that you've stated:

> Since query results contain only existing documents, the exists() method will always return true and getData() will never be null.

So, if you're dealing with a QueryDocumentSnapshot, you have a guarantee about what the exists() method will return.  If you're dealing with a DocumenSnapshot (that is not actually a QueryDocumentSnapshot that's been downcast), you don't have this guarantee.

I think you might just be putting too much weight on the fact that one is a subclass of the other.  Just use the one that you see in the API docs and don't cast anything to other types, unless you really know you need to do so.

Comment: However, one important distinction, is QueryDocumentSnapshot generally does not contain the reference path of the document, while DocumentSnapshot does.